# how to have two different colour schemes for command mode and edit mode in vim?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, colorscheme

I have been using vim for some time now but I am always unsure of which mode I am currently in and hence end up pressing Esc too often even in the command mode. This causes an irritating computer error beep. If there was a way to say toggle the background colour of vim from black to white if we enter command mode then there would be a lot of visual feedback about which mode I am currently in. how do I set it up?

Comment: You can also use `set belloff=esc` to stop esc beep.

Comment: Take a look at plug-ins such as [lightline.vim](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) which set the color of the status bar based on the Vim mode you're in. (They also typically list the mode quite explicitly at the beginning of the status line.)

Comment: If despite the previous comments you still want to change your colorscheme based on the mode you are in, I guess the easiest way to do it would be to make use of the autocommand event [`:h InsertEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#InsertEnter) and [`:h InsertLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#InsertLeave). They could allow you to automatically change the colorscheme when you enter and leave insert mode, that's not exactly what you asked for but I could work.

Comment: I’ve deleted a few comments which suggest that OP doesn’t know what they want or otherwise suggest answers. Please keep answers in answers, and remember that folks interact with tech in different ways. Extreme contrast can be a great visual reminder, especially for folks with vision impairments. (OP, welcome to [vi.se]! I’m certainly not assuming you *have* a vision impairment, but I would be upset at the thought of our usually very nice community failing to answer your question because they thought you shouldnt do what you have said would be best for you.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I will keep this in mind for the future, sorry about that.